# How to use System.TriggerOperation Enum

Tags: salesforce

There is a new feature provided by `Salesforce` that allows using `TriggerOperation` enum. I cannot find any example how to use this approach compared to traditional trigger. For example, how can I replace this code:

```apex
trigger TriggerName on ObjectName (before delete, before insert, before update,
                                   after delete, after insert, after update) {

    if (Trigger.isBefore) {
       if (Trigger.isInsert) { // do something }
       if (Trigger.isUpdate { // do something }
    } else {
       if (Trigger.isInsert) { // do something }
       if (Trigger.isUpdate { // do something }
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Answer from [salesforce.stackexchange.com](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/221054/system-triggeroperation-enum)**

According to `Summer 18` Apex developer guide, 7 new Enum values are introduced in System.TriggerOperation class.

`AFTER_DELETE
AFTER_INSERT
AFTER_UNDELETE
AFTER_UPDATE
BEFORE_DELETE
BEFORE_INSERT
BEFORE_UPDATE`

Similarly, a new variable is added in Trigger class named as `operationType`, which stores the context enum it is executing in.

Thus your trigger using switch case will be like :

```apex
 trigger AccountTrigger on Account (before delete, before insert, before update, 
                                    after delete, after insert, after update) {

    switch on Trigger.operationType {
        when AFTER_INSERT{
            //do after insert stuff
        }
        when AFTER_UPDATE{
            //Do after update stuff
        } 

    }
}
```

> there is no fall-through. After the code block is executed for a >particular when block, the switch statement exits

[Switch statement](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/2018/05/summer18-rethink-trigger-logic-with-apex-switch.html)

**My addition**

you can also do the following

```apex
 trigger AccountTrigger on Account (before delete, before insert, before update, 
                                    after delete, after insert, after update) {
    if (Trigger.operationType == TriggerOperation.AFTER_INSERT) {
        // do after insert stuff
    } 
}
```

And finally very personal IMHO - that's just a kind of syntactic sugar which give no profit for someone who use a good trigger architecture